# How can i put sms to income with notification?

Tags: android, sms, android-4.4-kitkat

I have app that work good in Android < 4.4

What do app:

1) Receive SMS

2) Read SMS and check for spam

3) If not spam: don't Abort brodcast receiver, so Messaging receive this SMS, show notification and work well

If Spam - abord receiver

I change app for KitKat, now app:

1) Receive SMS as a default SMS app

2) Read and check

3) If spam - do nothing. Sms dont go to Messaging(Messaging still app for read and write SMS)

If not spam - i manually write sms to inbox via ContentResolver,

What i need: in 3) i need standard user experience - notification, sound and vibro from messaging.
I can emulate vibro and sound, but manual created notification for messaging - is bad idea!
Can i send SMS directly to Messaging in Android? 
Are exists other methods?

Any help will appreciate

Comment: Your question is a little unclear, but if you're asking if you can pass an incoming message to the native SMS app while your app is default, then no. As default, your app is responsible for handling the Notifications.

Comment: It's historical behaviour. In android <4.4 i read sms and dont cancel it. After my application, sms was readed by messaging, and messaging show notification. 
My app has no UI for reading sms. And in 4.4 i write sms on receiving directly to messaging. Do I need create notification manual? This notification must open Messaging and show that sms on click.

Comment: That's true. However, starting with KitKat, when your app is the default SMS app, it is responsible for many, many things, including issuing Notifications. When an app is not the default SMS app, it is expected to change its behavior accordingly, and it will no longer handle such things. Your default app has to.

Comment: I made continue of conversation as new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26358471/how-create-notification-to-native-sms-app