# How create notification to native sms app

Tags: android, sms, android-4.4-kitkat

My app receive sms, check it, and save to income of native app

After [how can i put sms to income with notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26343390/how-can-i-put-sms-to-income-with-notification)
and
[display received messages in the default sms app and the native messaging app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26270881/display-received-messages-in-the-default-sms-app-and-the-native-messaging-app)

I decide to save sms to native app (messaging) and create notification for it
Can i made notification, that directly open Messaging with new sms? I mean, work like native notification?
What params in extras i need, and which intent i need invoke?

Comment: Why don't you just create the Notification yourself? I don't understand why you're trying to get around doing it.

Comment: Ok, I hadn't noticed you edited one of your previous comments, so I will elaborate. "Default" doesn't mean first in line to receive messages. It means that your app is expected to handle the composing, the sending, the receiving, the storing, the notifying. Everything. Not only for SMS, but MMS, as well. If your app's only functionality is hiding certain messages, then it shouldn't be a default SMS app.

Comment: Furthermore, your app can't be the default app, then just "hand off" the functionalities it doesn't cover. Any app that is not the default does not have standard write access to the Provider, and will lose many functionalities because of that. Some pretty much disable themselves completely if they're not the default.

Comment: Thanks for help, Mike. Ofcourse i will disable app, when it not default SMS app. I do, as write here http://android-developers.blogspot.ru/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html
I want use native app for send and read SMS. And it will be not default http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19560323/send-sms-message-using-non-default-sms-app-on-android-4-4 i think it possbile, but i will test it


And i will do notification manual for income sms. But i wont, that this notification will link on messaging native app. I wont make ui for view sms in my app. I think, it's acceptabpe case

Comment: I need it as default for cancel income sms ability :)

Comment: Now, i know, that native sms app become not able to send sms, if it not default. So, i need realize sms sending from my app, if i want sms filter (i want reject some income sms). It's death for project on KitKat. Why, Google, WHY?
Because i cant do another Hangout, its destroy user experience. Developing good sms app - more then all my project in times.

Comment: @Alex did you find any solution, I am in similar need.

Comment: @Alyas Yes, I did. I close the project :)